# Definite integral of derivative of function

Tags: definite-integrals

If I have the definite integral of the derivative of a function, is it the same as having the derivative of the definite integral of a function?

For the latter, it would be the derivative of the upper bound*the inside function at that upper bound.

But if the $d/dx$ is inside the integral symbol, is it the same process? I would assume it would be since moving terms in or out of the integral is flexible

Comment: Do you know the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus?

Answer (score 0):

If you perform the **definite** integral of a function, you will get a constant and differentiating a constant leads to **zero**.

Also having the definite integral of the derivative function is just the going to be the **average value** of the function **times** the **length of the interval**.

They are not equal.

Perhaps you meant the **indefinite** integral?

Comment: Actually what I meant was that you have d/dx(integral of f(t)) with the upper bound of the definite integral being something like x^2. So it would be 2x*f(x^2). But what if the d/dx was inside the integral symbol?

Comment: This might be of help. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule